# JavaFX: How to make Script files with extention .fx?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, javafx-1

I am new to Java Fx and I am using netbeans7.3.1 for Java FX ..
here there are `.java files and .fxml` files that can be created

I was wondering where would we right fx script.. so after searching i came to knew that JavaFX script can be written in `.fx file` can anyone tell me how to make these files as in netbeans i have not founded any way to make one

can anyone tell how to make these files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFX script (the .fx files) was created for the [now obsolete](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#8) and unsupported JavaFX 1.x distribution.  Support for JavaFX 1.x and .fx scripts was dropped from NetBeans after the NetBeans 6.9 release.  Use of JavaFX script and JavaFX 1.x is not recommended.

JavaFX 2.x+ is a complete rewrite of the JavaFX system in Java.  JavaFX 2.x also includes an XML based markup language named FXML.  All major JavaFX IDEs currently support JavaFX 2.x development based on .java and .fxml files.

Use of JavaFX 2.x+ is recommended.

If you wish to use a scripting language for JavaFX 2.x, you can use [JrubyFX](https://github.com/jruby/jrubyfx), [GroovyFX](http://groovyfx.org), [JavaScript](https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/jjs_fx), etc.  I recommend learning JavaFX programming with the [plain Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) before learning JavaFX programming with a scripting language.